# Return Key in Edit Command Mode Shortcuts - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

While willing to write `↩a` as a new shortcut for the `run all cells above` command I could not find how to specify the `return` symbol in Jupyter Notebook.

Writing `return-a` or `↩-a`in the `Edit Command Mode` does not work and the modifier is not specified in the help dialog.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return is not a modifier so shortcut like `↩-a` make little sens (pressing enter and A at the same time. `↩,a`  meaning `Return` key followed by `A` key make more sens, but Enter is so pervasive for many actions that it is not usable in user shortcuts. I would suggest you to open an issue on jupyter/notebook on GitHub to ask for `return` to be added as a convenient way to map to `↩` , though even if we do that we can't guaranty that it will work. If you are willing to try to code that yourself, have  a look at `keyboard.js`, the mapping from `enter` to displaying `↩` is already done in `quickhelp.js`, for mac at least.